# how can i show form fields on clicking the link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

this is my form page, i want to keep this form hidden under link or button called change password once the user click on it, it must display this form. Any help would be appreciated.

```
           <form action="#buildurl('user.change_password')#" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="email" id="email" value="#session.auth.email#">

                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="label-control" for="password">Enter current password</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                         <input type="password" name="password" id="password" >
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="label-control" for="password_new">Enter New password</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                         <input type="password" name="password_new" id="password_new" >
                    </div>
                 </div>                 

                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="label-control" for="password_confirm">Enter confirm password</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                         <input type="password" name="password_confirm" id="password_confirm" >
                    </div>
                 </div>

                <div>
                    <button type="submit" name="submit_password" id="submit_password" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
             </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want this : [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dTHyy/), if it's hidden ,it will be shown ,else , it will be hidden.
I suggest to add id to your form and replace `'form'` in jQuery code by your `#id` , to avoid problems if you have more than one form.

**JQuery:**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 $('form').hide();//hide initially
 $("#showButton").click(function(e){
   $('form ').toggle('slow');//or just show instead of toggle

 });
</script>
```

Add jQuery file to your code in the `<head>` of your html page:

```
<script type='text/javascript'src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: initially i don't want to display form fields, I just want to show a link or button once the user click on the button it should display form fields.

Comment: this works exactly what i am looking in fiddle but not on my system. is i need to have something ?

Comment: You need to have jquery , and wrape js code inside <script type='text/javascript'>......</script> check my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, i haven't include that link that's what it was not working.

Answer (score 0):

Give your form and button IDs. Then:

CSS

```
#yourForm { display: none; }
```

JS

```
$(document).on('click', '#changePassword', function () {
  $('#yourForm').show();
});
```